# Angular HTTP sync request in Life Cycle event

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

In Angular2+, How to make sure a HTTP request (or Observable) finish before it go to the next line.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvtfln

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  name = 'AngularX';
  systemPreference: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    //get system preference, it is used in whole app,
    //it needs to be available so other component can use it.
    this.http.get("https://data.hawaii.gov/api/views/usep-nua7/rows.json").subscribe(res=>{
      //How to make it is done before go to the next life circle event?
      this.systemPreference = res;
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
    //the below got undefined, I expect the subscriber must be done at ngOnInit 
    //before reaching this function (ngAfterViewInit)
    console.log(this.systemPreference);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you don't return anything from the method there's no way that it could wait but, regardless, angular doesn't support this anyway. You need to adjust your code. Why do you need to perform part of the logic in one hook and part in the other? There are frameworks, like Aurelia, that support asynchronous lifecycle hooks, but angular isn't one of them. Even if it were however, this wouldn't be a good use case for that support. Please explain why you want to perform part of the logic in a different life cycle hook

Comment: Imaging that it is system information and used in the whole app, it needs to be available so other component can use it.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is using a BehaviorSubject or just a Subject.  Consider making the following changes:

```
systemPreference = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    //get system preference
    this.http.get("https://data.hawaii.gov/api/views/usep-nua7/rows.json").subscribe(res=>{
      systemPreference.next(res);
    })


  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
  systemPreference.subscribe(pref => 
    console.log(pref ));
  }
```

I would consider this fix a hack, where the correct approach would be to handle this reactively.  It's hard to give you guidance on the reactive approach without having the larger picture.

-Isaac

Comment: Here's the StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krno5t

Comment: Thanks, Isaac for your quick response.
I need the data available so other components can use it.
Imaging the systemPreference is used by the whole app not just ngAfterViewInit of AppComponent. So, it must be ready before other components getting init.

Comment: Take another look at my Stack Blitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krno5t.  I gave you an example of how a SubComponent would use that data only when it's available.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krno5t

In the latest version, the application will only load the SubComponent after the preferences have been loaded.

Comment: You are so zeal, Isaac. Thanks so much.
Because the systemPreference is not only used by direct sub-component, I expect to put it into a service, so any component/intercepter/... can use it. But as we see, because http is async request, there is a case that a component is getting init without systemPreference.
You can image I need a resolver for the whole app, not only component. Something must be done before Angular inits any other components.

Comment: As far as other components being initialized before the data is available, this is the purpose of the *ngIf.  It will only initialize the component when the condition is true; conversely, when the condition is false again it will call ngOnDestroy and dispose of your component.

As far as sharing the data, then you'll want to create a service to manage your state.

Comment: I updated the Stack Blitz to illustrate using a service to manage your state.  I also added two components that depend on the retrieved data.

Comment: Thanks, IkeMtz. Currently, I am using the service to broadcast the data when it is available by Observable. But, it has an issue in a complex app, so I need to seek another way to make it be simple.